# 400 Bad Request when using FB.AppRequest with ids received from FB.API( "me/invitable_friends"...)

Tags: unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk

I'm trying to make a custom friends invite dialog for my Unity game on Facebook. So first got some fine invitable_friends tokens from call to:

```
FB.API( "me/invitable_friends" );
```

Tokens are looking fine, they contain correct names and correct image urls.
Then I'm trying to send invitations with

```
FB.AppRequest(message, invitable_friends,null..);
```

where invitable_friends is string[] containing some id-s of before mentioned friends.
FB shows it's dialog with proper name(s) of friends but some time later in Unity Console reports error:

```
400 Bad Request
UnityEngine.Debug:LogError(Object)
FbDebug:Error(String)
Facebook.FallbackData:JSFallback(String)
Facebook.AsyncRequestDialogPost:CallbackWithErrorHandling(FBResult)
Facebook.<Start>c__Iterator0:MoveNext()
```

Testing WebPlayer build under Chrome gives more specific error in debug console:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/integrated_plugin_apprequests/?users=XXX&locale=en_GB&integrated_plugin_secret=...&access_token=...
```

which is link to:

"error": {
      "message": "(#100) XXX does not resolve to a valid user ID",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 100
   }

I'm using Facebook Unity SDK 6.0 but repeated this error on 6.1 Beta also.

So it seems id taken from invitable_friends are not correctly resolved by Facebook! Which is bad. Anyone has any idea how to fix it?